# ngFor radio buttons unable to deselect

Tags: html, angular, radio-button, ngfor

I'm trying to make a quiz. I am able to make the questions and answers appear the way I want, but the radio buttons aren't working correctly. Once clicked, they do not become unmarked, either by clicking them again or clicking another one. They do pass the value of the last one that was clicked, but you can't reclick one that was already clicked. (ie. you click answer 1, then 3, then 1 again. both 1 and 3 are marked but the value of 3 is passed)

```
const quizQuestions = [
    {
        index: 0,
        formName: "q0",
        question: "Ready?",
        options: [
            {
                option: "1",
                answer: "Begin!",
                affectUp: [],
                affectDown: []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        index: 1,
        formName: "q1",
        question: "You\u2019re a “jack-of-all-trades”.",
        options: [
            {
                option: "1",
                answer: "Strongly Agree"
            },
            {
                option: "2",
                answer: "Neutral"
            },
            {
                option: "3",
                answer: "Strongly Disagree"
       }
                

]
```

```
<div *ngFor="let qz of quizQuestions; let i = index;">
    <div class="card" *ngIf="i === quizNumber">
        {{qz.question}}
        <div class="card-body">
            <div *ngFor="let opt of qz.options; let i2 = index;">
                <form [formGroup]="quizForm">
                    <label for="o-{{i}}-{{i2}}">{{opt.answer}}</label>
                    <input type="radio"  id="o-{{i}}-{{i2}}" formControlName="q{{i}}" [value]="opt.option">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.quizForm = this.formbuilder.group(
      {
        q0: [''],
        q1: [''],
        q2:[''],
        q3: [''],
        q4: ['']
      }
    )
  }
```

[image: unmarked]
[image: all marked]

Comment: can you share your formGroup code ?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Ok, yes that is working. I could have sworn I tried that way, but I guess I did something different. Thank you!

Comment: @GRD - as I've commented on other questions where you have responded: Please delete your contact info, and refrain from posting code to an external site. If you want to answer, then please post as a proper answer. I suggest taking the tour to learn more about answering questions.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating as many `<form>`s as you have options because you're placing it inside your `*ngFor`. Also, radio buttons need to all have the same `name` in order for the browser to regard them as part of the same set of options.

Take the `<form>` out of the `*ngFor` iterations and give all related radio buttons the same `name` attribute.

Comment: I actually tried that first, but it acts the same way whether form is inside or outside. Also, formControlName is where I name the radio buttons, and they are given unique names for each group.

Comment: It doesn't actually act the same way, although it may appear to. Your code currently creates `n` form elements, which is never going to work. HTML radio buttons require a `name` attribute to link them to each other: the browser can't tell they're linked by their FormControlName.

Comment: Your form element needs to contain all of the controls for `quizForm` once and only once.